# No Empty<T> method in Array class?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk9FI.png)

Why compiler tells me it doesn't exist? I have last SDK installed and netcoreapp3.1 as targeted framework.

```cs
public SomeDefinedType[] GetRecords()
{
        return new System.Array.Empty<SomeDefinedType>();
}
```

Comment: Post your code. Images can't be googled or compiled. [Array.Empty<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.empty?view=netcore-3.1) isn't missing. You may be trying to use the wrong `Array` class though. You may have a library that also defines an `Array`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that what @PanagiotisKanavos mentions about posting your code means that you should post a [mcve], not just a text version of what is in that screenshot. We actually need to see your actual code, or at least a small copy of it that still exhibits the problem, otherwise there is no way for anyone here to answer your question, just to provide things to look into and guesses.

Comment: That error suggests you are doing something like `Array.Empty<int> myArray;` when you should be doing `int[] myArray = Array.Empty<int>()`;

Comment: Hope I made it more clear

Comment: @liruxed remove `new`. `Array.Empty<SomeDefinedType>()` is a function that returns an empty array, not a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.Empty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.empty?view=netcore-3.1) is a function that returns an empty array, not a type. It can't be used with `new`. Just return the function's result:

```
public SomeDefinedType[] GetRecords()
{
    return System.Array.Empty<SomeDefinedType>();
}
```